# Synchronized calls using axios and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, async-await, axios

I am quite new to node js and i seem to have a persisting problem which i have not gotten a solution to.

In my app, i am using Socket to interact with the server & Axios to interact with an API.
The code runs as expected and returns the results as expected but not in the preferred order.
**Here is my struggle**
On the client:

```
function getPreviousChat(data) {
  socket.emit('getChat', data);
}

function loadChat(conversation) {
  socket.emit('parseMessage', conversation);
}

socket.on('loadChat', function(conversation) {
  if (conversation) {
    for(var i = 0; i < conversation.length; i++){
      loadChat(conversation[i]);
    }
  }
});

socket.on('newMessage', function(data) {
    $('div').append(data.message)
});
```

And using axios on the server:

```
socket.on('getChat', function(data) {
    axios.get(api)
      .then(response => {
        io.sockets.emit('loadChat', response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });

socket.on('parseMessage', function(data) {
    axios.get(api2)
      .then(response => {
        io.sockets.emit('newMessage', {
          msg: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
```

The function **getPreviousChat** is called and it works fine and it returns the chat messages, however, it is not displayed in the order which it is saved in the database. I know it is because node is asynchronous and is not waiting to get a response before proceeding to the next function call but i would like to know how to get it to load the data in an orderly manner.

Comment: Are you refering to `loadChat` on the client?

Comment: You can put your `socket.on('newMessage'...` inside your `socket.on('loadChat'` callback, to make sure it happens in that order. By the way, you're missing a closing `}` for the `if` statement in there

Comment: you need to save the messages with timestamp and then retrieve it sorting it with that timestamp for it to display in order

Comment: @SunilLama when i run console.log(conversation) right after checking if(conversation), the console shows the messages in the correct order.

Comment: @blex Yes i noticed the closing tag and the response.datag. Please post the answer as a snippet and if it works i will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Jacob Yes, loadChat is called from the client.

Comment: I can see that you are calling api2 for each conversation, but not using the conversation data that is being passed into the api2 call?

Comment: @SunilLama The data is being used in the broader scope of the code.